# jq select match pattern but not if preceded by other pattern

Tags: scripting, regular-expression, jq

An application called "vagrant packer" always downloads the iso and checksum file from the remote location every time I run it, so I'm creating a script that downloads the iso to a local location, but only if the published_at date is higher than my local one. If it is, I download the iso and checksum and then store the published date on a local .conf file.

So I try to get the download url of the checksum from the [project's github api url](https://api.github.com/repos/manjaro-sway/manjaro-sway/releases/latest),
however the download_url needs to first not match and then match a pattern.

It needs to not contain "unstable" and end with ".iso.sha512".

*run.sh*

```
...
    echo downloading checksum..
    checksum_download_url=$(curl -s $github_latest_api_url | jq -r '.assets[].browser_download_url|select(match(".(?!unstable).iso.sha512"))')
...
```

As you can see, I'm trying to first get the correct download url,
before doing a curl download command in the next line.

I've made an attempt,
but I just can't figure out what the regex of the match function.
I'm still getting either no result, a syntax error, or the unstable line included.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source ./uploads/mai-base.conf

prerelease=$(curl -s $github_latest_api_url | jq -r '.prerelease')

if [ !prerelease ]; then
  
  r_publish_date=$(date -d $(curl -s $github_latest_api_url | jq -r '.published_at') +%s)
  l_publish_date=$(date -d $publish_date +%s)

  if [ $r_publish_date -gt $l_publish_date ]; then
    echo downloading checksum..
    checksum_download_url=$(curl -s $github_latest_api_url | jq -r '.assets[].browser_download_url|select(match(".(?!unstable).iso.sha512"))')
    echo $checksum_download_url
    #curl -L $download_url 
    echo downloading iso..
    # downloading iso code goes here..

    # date saving to mai-base.conf goes here..
  fi
fi

# Start packer application..
# PACKER_LOG=1 packer build -var $ISO_VERSION manjaro-arm-installer.pkr.hcl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I would probably do two separate tests for simplicity, instead of trying to get negative/positive look-behinds/aheads right. Also, use `test()` rather than `match()` if you're just interested in whether a regular expression matches or not:

```bash
jq '.assets[].browser_download_url|select( (test("unstable")|not) and test("iso.sha512$"))'
```

As for your script, you use `[ !prerelease ]` which is not using the `prerelease` variable.  What you probably wanted to say was

```bash
if [ "$prerelease" != false ]; then
```

This could be done without an extra variable, though:

```bash
if ! curl -s "$github_latest_api_url" | jq -e .prerelease >/dev/null
then
    ...
fi
```

The `-e` option to `jq` makes the utility exit with an exit status that depends on the last evaluation.

To avoid having to fetch your JSON document three times, save the fetched JSON document in a temporary file. To avoid having to parse it three times, get all the data out of it in one go:

```bash
curl -s ... |
jq -r '[.prerelease, .published_at, (.assets[].browser_download_url|select( (test("unstable")|not) and test("iso.sha512$"))) ] | @tsv' |
{
    IFS=$'\t' read -r prerelease r_publish_date checksum_download_url
    if [ "$prerelease" != false ]; then
        # use "$r_publish_date" and "$checksum_download_url"
    fi
}
```

Comment: With some minor tweaks this worked. 
```
if [ $prerelease == false ]; the
```

Because it should run when it's not a prerelease.

```
test(".iso.sha512"), test("iso.z01"), test("iso.zip")  
```

Because I want the iso file as well, but for unknown reasons it's split in two, so I need the z01 file as well.